# Loop custom array from mongoose returned empty

Tags: javascript, loops, mongoose, model

here is my problem

I want to loop data from two entities `Project` and `User`, my `Project` entity have a field with `User` id called creatorId.

I looped it and tried to add my user data `_id`, `displayname` and `avatarUrl`.

For now that work, but when I send it from the backend to the frontend nothing appears, like the array is empty.

```
const projectList = [];
  Project.find({}, function(err, projects) {
     projects.map(project => {
      User.findById(project.creatorId, function(err, creator){
        projectList.push({
          _id: project._id,
          title: project.title,
          description: project.description,
          avatarUrl: project.avatarUrl,
          creationDate: project.creationDate,
          projectCreator: {
            _id: creator._id,
            displayname: creator.displayname,
            avatarUrl: creator.avatarUrl
          },
          git: project.git
        })
      })
    })
  });
  res.send(projectList);
```

Comment: what's the output if you `console.log(projectList)` right before `res.send(projectList);`?

Comment: by the way, please notice mongoose's `findById` function is async. you should `res.send` after `projectList.push({ ... })`

Comment: @GrafiCode the output for the first ``console.log`` is my working custom list who grows at each push in the loop

for the send if I send just after the push it's breaking the ``res.send`` with error who told me that i can't ``res.send`` multiple time